# Angular 6: subscribe component to a service event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript2.0

I need to change message txt in a component according to a server response status. The problem is I don't know how to listen to that event in my component ts file and call a function declared in it. Maybe there is some better approach to show such notifications

handle error ts:

```js
  catchErrors(resp:any) {
    if (resp.status == 200) {
      this.message = 'Запрос выполнен успешною Код: ' + resp.status;
    }
    else if (resp.status == 400) {
      this.message = 'Неверный запрос. Код ошибки: ' + status;
    }
    else if (resp.status == 404) {
      this.message = 'Сущность не найдена в системе. Код ошибки: ' + status;
    }
    else if (resp.status == 500) {
      this.message = 'Ошибка сервера. Код ошибки: ' + status;
    }
return this.messageService.showMessage(this.message);
  }
```

message service ts :

```js
  showMessage(message) {
    return this.message = message;
  }
```

And I need to run this function every time I get a response from a server. It is in messages.component.ts:

```js
   showNotification() {
    this.message = this.messageService.message;
  }
```

Comment: r u catching the errors in interceptor?

Comment: Sheik Althaf, no

Comment: have you tried using subjects ?

Comment: `return this.message = message;` Does the `return` is really required? I think you are accessing a property of a service so you don't need the return there. and the other return too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subjects to get this job done :

In your `message.service.ts` declare a `Subject` :

```
messageSubject : Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
```

Inside the `showMessage()` :

```
showMessage(message) {
    this.messageSubject.next(message);
 }
```

And in your `component` , inside the `ngOnInit()` , subscribe to the `messageSubject` like this :

```
this.messageService.messageSubject.subscribe((message : string) => {

//your message will be available here as ``message`` and you can implement your notification logic using this message 
})
```

Comment: @TonyaMilner glad i could help . happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can create a `private` `BehaviorSubject<string>` in your `MessageService`, and expose it as a `public` `Observable` by using `asObservable`.

You can also create a `setMessage` method on this service so that it could push the new message down the stream which the `private` `BehaviorSubject<string>` created.

This can then be used by the `handleHandler`.

And then you can simply `subscribe` to the `public` `Observable` that was exposed by your `MessageService`.

This would look something like this in code:

MessageService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

  private message: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  public message$: Observable<string> = this.message.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.comm/users')
      .subscribe(
        res => console.log(res),
        err => this.errorHandler(err)
      );
  }

  setMessage(newMessage) {
    this.message.next(newMessage);
  }

  private errorHandler(error) {
    this.message.next('Got an error')
  }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  message;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.message$.subscribe(message => this.message = message);
    this.messageService.getData();
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<p>Message from the Message Service: {{ message }}</p>
```

**There's just one catch here:**

You can't create another service for error handling as your error handler service would rely on your message service and vice versa. This would create what is called a Circular Dependency and thus throw an error.

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service-eg-using-behavior-subject?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmessage.service.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Thank you for the solution)